# Blazor WASM adds "/authentication" to path after login

Tags: authentication, blazor, identity, webassembly

First I want you to excuse me that I am an English speaker.
I have an error that I have not been able to solve and I have not been able to find any comments from someone who has had a similar problem.

After login the page does not address correctly. Apparently /authentication is added to the path and that it creates the error as it can't find _framework/blazor.webassembly.js,

The correct path should be
https://localhost:7293/login-callback?code=764B947CAE732C640B3D01E7C3E9C0DE3C13F0E8F6578975DA13079053CD9376-1&scope=ProtegiaWasm.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=28d572d1a9074ae28f184d8820262bb9&session_state=qOB10fFgJDRubXqkIcc6lvlizTa5xMmIAhRLuTw3d4c.D640C48FAD733ADDECB15032D1F52F06&iss=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7293

But, instead of that, this route appears
https://localhost:7293/authentication/login-callback?code=764B947CAE732C640B3D01E7C3E9C0DE3C13F0E8F6578975DA13079053CD9376-1&scope=ProtegiaWasm.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=28d572d1a9074ae28f184d8820262bb9&session_state=qOB10fFgJDRubXqkIcc6lvlizTa5xMmIAhRLuTw3d4c.D640C48FAD733ADDECB15032D1F52F06&iss=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7293

Is there a way to modify the /_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js
so that it is directed to the correct path?